# UML fragment to prevent the further executions?

Tags: uml, assert, diagram, sequence-diagram

What is a UML fragment is using in a case representing a check operation that either stops the further execution on a failed check or lets it go, kind of a programming statement `if role != 'admin': break:`?

I found the `assert` fragment seems to fit the case.

The idea on a diagram:
[image]

Is the fragment used properly to represent that operation `change_sensetive_settings()` is executing only if a user has `admin` role?

Comment: You're mixing Activity with Sequence in your diagram. That ain't right.

Comment: You should explain the mixing, don't you?

Comment: You're using flow start/end which are only legal with actions in activity diagrams.

Comment: Let it be incorrect. Atm i would like to realize whether it's possible to warn about the case using a sequence diagram and how. And if it's possible, what a visual element is to apply for the case. ASSERT fragment seems to be an appropriate visual element in my opinion. If it isn't you are welcome to suggest something else.

Comment: https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html#operator-assert

Comment: Honestly, I think that in most cases application of interactions is wrong as it tends to be graphical programming. And that would be failure by design. Keep the SDs simple and eventually use a note. They should give an overview, not programmatic details. My POV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of assert, which seems to be meant for visual procedureal programming rather than clean design of valid behavior.   There is not much information on `assert` fragment in the standard:

> The interactionOperator assert designates that the CombinedFragment represents an assertion. The sequences of the operand of the assertion are the only valid continuations. All other continuations result in an invalid trace.

But the way `assert` is used here, seems confusing in this regard: you just show a constraint `{ user.role == 'admin }` on the server lifeline, whereas the continuation will result in a message being initiated on the client side.

To disambiguate this diagram, I'd recommend to enclose in the `assert` fragment the sequence made of the `register_user()` message, followed by the return message and your constraint.  This would clearly relate the outcome regarding the user role constraint to the registration.

But this only tells a part of the story.  Because, what does it mean in pratice that  "All other continuations result in an invalid trace" ? Assert, just tells an assumption. Is there anything ahead of this interaction that makes this assumption realistic?  If not what should happen if the user has insufficient authorisations?

For all these reasons, I'd rather recommend to use here and `alt`  to show the normal flow,  but also suggest that if the user does not have the right authorisation, something should happen (and on which side: client or server).

Comment: `alt` fragment is a good replacement in my real case. I tried to find a way as a typical programmer to depict a logical check to go further if it is successful or interrupt control flow otherwise.

Comment: I think `assert` is, what most people mistake for the semantics of a sequence diagram. They assume only the modeled sequence of events is valid. However, this is not true. A sequence diagram without assert just models one valid sequence of events. It doesn't mean, other sequences are invalid. Therefore, the inclusion of `register_user()` in the assert fragment doesn't change much.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer interesting remark about the diagram representing only one scenario which doesn't exclude other valid scenario. This is yet another great argument against (mis?)using SD for visual programming.  Of course, you are right: including `register_user()` does not change this truth nor the technical semantic.  However, it has the benefit of clarifying the intent of the assertion (i.e. asserting that the outcome of the registration is ok). It suggests that both should be viewed together.  I personally believe that design intent is a key element in the lifecycle of a system.

Answer (score 1):

No, I think `assert` is not used correctly. Here is why:

The specification defines:

> The interactionOperator assert designates that the CombinedFragment
> represents an assertion. The sequences of the operand of the assertion
> are the only valid continuations. All other continuations result in an
> invalid trace.

That means, the state invariant `{user.role='admin'}` is the only valid continuation after the reply to the `register_user()` message. This would rule out other outcomes. I don't think, this is what you had in mind.

So, simply remove the `assert` fragment. Since the sequence diagram only shows *one possible* scenario, it doesn't mean, that other scenarios are not valid. You could have another sequence diagram, where the state invariant is `{user.role='student'}`.

If you want to show more scenarios in one diagram, you could use an `alt` fragment. However, as others have pointed out, the purpose of the sequence diagram is not visual programming. Therefore, striving for a complete description of all possible scenarios is not appropriate.

###### minor mistakes

There are some minor mistakes in the diagram. Most of them have been pointed out by others, but to make this a complete answer:

- The first message could be a found message. Then the circle would be filled and the name of the message would be on the arrow. It could also come from a gate. This would be shown by originating the arrow from the frame. I would recommend the latter.
- The state invariant should probably move down below the reception of `change_sensitive_settings` because the user could still try to change them. Only the server can decide to reject this request. Or it must move to the client lifeline, if you want to specify that the client only sends the message, if s/he is an admin.
- The arrow at the end of the diagram should be dashed, since it is the reply to the synchronuous message it begins with. And again, it should end in a black circle denoting a lost message or, better, at the frame of the diagram.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you for improving my understanding. I ended up removing the assert fragment. Other details are taken into consideration.